# Conditional helper doesn't behave as expected in Handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js

Trying to learn about Handlebars custom block helpers and conditional helpers, I've created a simple example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/goyosoyo/m2uf9g92/).  The custom helper returns true but the conditional expression doesn't appear to respond correctly to the value passed out of the block helper

```
<script id="test" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<h3>{{title}}</h3>
<p>custom helper returns: {{isCategory}}</p>
<p>conditional result: {{#if isCategory}}yes{{else}}no{{/if}}</p>
<p><em>I would expect the result to be 'yes'</em></p>
</script>
```

What's not happening properly in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conditional `{{#if isCategory}}` is looking for `isCategory` in your data object, and since it doesn't exist.. False/No.

The conditional block will not evaluate your custom helper, it will only look in your data object passed in to the template.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  A custom helper returns code to be inserted into the dom; it cannot be used for other purposes like the one I was attempting.  Thanks.

Comment: One thing you could do is to write your own conditional block helper that you could use in place of `{{#if}}`. An example of this is in the project I am working on now. It is a SPA which grabs all of a users permissions on initial page load. I want to hide or show some things based on whether or not a user has the required permission, so I wrote a conditional helper which would check if they have it. `{{#permission 'CREATE_USERS'}}<button>Create User</button>{{/permission}`

Comment: This is essentially what I am trying to accomplish. In your {{#permission}}  example, is the block helper returning a boolean that displays or hides the create user button or is it returning (or not) the button html?

Comment: `Handlebars.registerHelper('permission', function(permission, options) {
  if(CurrentUser.isAuthorizedTo(permission)) {
    return options.fn(this);
  } else {
    return options.inverse(this);
  }
});`

You want to return `options.fn(this)` if your condition is met, `options.inverse(this)` otherwise. This allows you to do something like:

`{{#permission 'CREATE_USER'}}
    <button>Create User</user>
{{else}}
    <h5>You aren't authorized to create a user</h5>
{{/permission}}`